# Where could I find some free/commerical stock icon packs?

Tags: icons

What are some free/commercial stock icon sets?

Comment: Any question with the word "best" in the the title is going to be subjective. What are your criteria for "best"? If you list those there will be an objectively correct (or nearly correct) answer.

Comment: Meh, I don't think we need to enforce an objective answer here. This question is a good referential resource for UI designers. Perhaps Simon could reword it as "What are some good stock icon packs?" to be more accurate and fit within the Q&A model.

Comment: This should be a community wiki. The question should be rephrased to "What are good sources for icon packs?"

Comment: Questions that ask users to contribute to a list of answers should be marked [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). I converted this question.

Comment: Agreed. I changed the formulation from "the best" to "good" as suggested by many.

Comment: @Dan - I also think "good" is subjective too ;)

Comment: @Patrick - please show me where in the post you referenced does it state that list questions should be community wiki

Comment: @Charles I don't know if it's written down anywhere, but we were pretty consistent about making list questions CW on this site for the first couple of months. Since then, the use of CW has been discouraged. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better

Comment: @Patrick - that's because it was being misused.

Comment: @Charles I don't disagree with you. Unfortunately, CW is a one-way action. I can't change it back now.

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - because, like all SE sites, list questions are explicitly discouraged if not banned outright.

Comment: @Charles - I still don't understand *the reasoning*. The *community* wants this open (I don't have enough rep on this SE site to vote to open) - look at the number of up votes! Additionally for UI/UX, this is a *wonderful* resource.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - It doesn't matter - there are certain rules for the platform and they have very good reasons for the rules. And there are lots of things that could be good resources for the users of this site, but that doesn't mean that they should all be here. This is a question and answer site, not a discussion site. It is also not intended to be the be all, end all location for UX resources. This question is also inappropriate for Stack Exchange because it could easily be answered by a simple Google search.

Answer (score 47):

Here is a list of all my icon links, some for free and some for pay:

**Completely free**

- [www.iconpot.com/](http://www.iconpot.com/)
- [www.axialis.com/free/icons/](http://www.axialis.com/free/icons/)
- [commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Nuvola_icons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aNuvola_icons)
- [www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/)
- [www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/09/03/symbols-buttons-and-icons-for-free/](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/09/03/symbols-buttons-and-icons-for-free/)
- [tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project)
- [www.interfacelift.com/icons-win/index.php?sort=date](http://www.interfacelift.com/icons-win/index.php?sort=date)
- [www.fatcow.com/free-icons](http://www.fatcow.com/free-icons)
- [www.tripwiremagazine.com/icons/design/50-top-free-icon-resources.html](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/icons/design/50-top-free-icon-resources.html)

**Free + Paid for**

- [www.mezzoblue.com/icons/chalkwork/collection/](http://www.mezzoblue.com/icons/chalkwork/collection/)
- [www.icondock.com/](http://www.icondock.com/)
- [www.axialis.com/free/icons/](http://www.axialis.com/free/icons/)
- [www.axialis.com/free/icons/](http://www.axialis.com/free/icons/)
- [www.iconsreview.com/](http://www.iconsreview.com/)
- [www.icojoy.com/](http://www.icojoy.com/)
- [www.glyfx.com/index.html](http://www.glyfx.com/index.html)
- [www.fasticon.com/stockicons.html](http://www.fasticon.com/stockicons.html)
- [www.readyicons.com/](http://www.readyicons.com/)
- [sweetie.sublink.ca/](http://sweetie.sublink.ca/)
- [www.freeiconsweb.com/index.html](http://www.freeiconsweb.com/index.html)
- [www.websiteicons.com/about/cipres](http://www.websiteicons.com/about/cipres)
- [www.iconfactory.com/stockicons](http://www.iconfactory.com/stockicons)
- [www.glyphicons.com/](http://www.glyphicons.com/)

**Paid for**

- [www.ionworx.com/icons.html](http://www.ionworx.com/icons.html)
- [www.planeticons.com/](http://www.planeticons.com/)
- [www.glyfz.com/glyfz2007.htm](http://www.glyfz.com/glyfz2007.htm)
- [www.windows-icons.com/](http://www.windows-icons.com/)
- [www.icondesignlab.com/portfolio-toolbar-icons.php](http://www.icondesignlab.com/portfolio-toolbar-icons.php)
- [www.awicons.com/stockicons/?discount=stockico2](http://www.awicons.com/stockicons/?discount=stockico2)
- [www.marvilla.us/](http://www.marvilla.us/)
- [www.yellowicon.com/](http://www.yellowicon.com/index.php)
- [stock-icons.luckyicon.com/](http://stock-icons.luckyicon.com/)

Needless to say ... I like looking at icons!

Comment: It would've been nicer as two lists (free and paid for), but still a very impressive list.

Comment: @Bernhard Hofmann Added :) Please edit where I'm mistaken. I've used the `F+C` rating if the site provides *both* - even if it's only *one* free set.

Comment: Arranged into free, paid for and free + paid for. I have also removed duplicate entries / entries that direct to each other.

Answer (score 27):

I love the Silk famfamfam icons personally.

http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/

Comment: Also see the Silk Companion #1 set: http://damieng.com/creative/icons/silk-companion-1-icons

Comment: And the Silk Companion II Pack: http://www.cagintranet.com/archive/download-famfamfam-silk-companion-2-icon-pack/

Answer (score 9):

The [Fugue and Diagona icons](http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/) are free if you give credit, alternatively you can pay not to have to.

Comment: Fugue is one of my favorite icon sets

Answer (score 8):

What about a search engine for icons? I find http://www.iconfinder.com/ very useful... it's actually more useful than having a single icon pack available.

Comment: I LOVE Icon Finder. So useful.

Answer (score 7):

The Pictos sets are worth every (reasonable) cent. I've used them more than any other set since I picked them up.

http://pictos.drewwilson.com/

Answer (score 4):

For iPhone apps you **must know** that [Glyphish](http://glyphish.com/) icon set exists !

To find an icon you are looking for I advise to take a look at [Icon Finder](http://www.iconfinder.com/).

Although, there is no *best* icon packs. You can find thousand websites with great icon packs. This question should be a community Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

[Icon Dock](http://icondock.com/icons) have have some nice icons too, but it's commercial.

Answer (score 2):

The [Tango Icon Set](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project) is a nice addition I use a lot, next to the Famfamfam already named.

Answer (score 1):

[IconsPedia](http://www.iconspedia.com/) have a great collections of free icons.
[DryIcons](http://dryicons.com/free-icons/) also have some great icons.

Comment: Didn't like iconspedia too much, but iconsdock is awesome! @Jeremie - why don't you post that as a separate answer?

Answer (score 1):

If price is a factor, iconexperience.com has a huge collection for a few hundred bucks.

Answer (score 1):

These are quite expensive but are a nice family of icons:

http://helveticons.ch/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, a good source for icons is iStockPhoto.  Search for "icon set" and you'll come up with nearly 30,000 results and many of them are very very inexpensive considering the quality you are getting (and most are vector based).

http://www.istockphoto.com/file_search.php?action=file&text=icon%20set&oldtext=icon%20set

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the icons from [GlyFx](http://www.glyfx.com/index.html).

They have some free packs (see http://www.glyfx.com/products/free.html) if you working with a small (or non-existent) budget.

Some time ago my work licensed one of their multipacks, giving us a wide library of graphics that we use across all our projects. Consistent quality and styling - recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Tabsicon.com are getting regular updates, and is available in both color, and a simple glyph version. Great for crossplatform use.

[www.tabsicons.com](http://www.tabsicons.com)